# Why won't my ActionBar show

Tags: android

I have my `values-v11/styles.xml` file as follows, but the ActionBar won't show on my Nexus 5 (API 19). It manages to style the `TextView` and `background`, so the Theme is being set, just not with the ActionBar. What's going wrong?

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView" >
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextView.Header">
        <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.lobsterdoodle.kkworkhours.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="uk.lobsterdoodle.kkworkhours.app.WeekActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
package uk.lobsterdoodle.kkworkhours.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TableRow;


public class WeekActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

        ...some non-actionbar related stuff...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.week, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any other folders for values as well like `values-v14` etc?

Comment: Try taking out the background item on the actionbar and see if that  does something?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I have `values`, `values-v11` and `values-v21`. So API 19 should use v11.

Comment: @Shahzad - Removing the background item on the actionbar made no difference I'm afraid.